# Cross Domain jQuery Ajax Response returns Undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I **am** able to get a JSON response using the code below:

```
var campaign = {id:1};
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: campaign,
      url: 'http://getfrontclick.com/web/track.php',

      //contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: false
      },

      headers: {
      },

      success: function(response) {
        $('#response pre').html( response );
      },

      error: function() {
        alert("Fail");
      }
    });
```

It displays:

```
{"id":"1","username":"admin","email":"alex@xevs.com"}
```

I am trying to assign each one of these JSON items into a variable so I can echo them onto the page individually. Unfortunately I am having trouble with this.

If I add the following code under the "success" portion of the jQuery ajax response, I get "undefined"

```
var json_obj = $.parseJSON(response);//parse JSON

        var output="<ul>";
        for (var i in json_obj) 
        {
            output+="<li>" + json_obj[i].username + ",  " + json_obj[i].email + "</li>";
        }
        output+="</ul>";

        $("#sample").html(output);
```

This returns: `undefined, undefined
undefined, undefined
undefined, undefined`

Can anyone help with this? It would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your JSON is a single object, not an array. Why are you looping over it?

Comment: @Barmar Okay - better question: How can I get my object into an array so I can individually echo items on the page? This is what I am trying to accomplish as my end goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API you're calling just returns a single object, not an array. So just access the object properties directly, without looping or indexing it. And since it's not a list, there's no need to use `<ul>`.

```
var json_obj = $.parseJSON(response);//parse JSON
output = json_obj.username + ",  " + json_obj.email;
$("#sample").html(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

On success, most likely jQuery already detected is a JSON and the `response` is already parsed.
Considering the JSON you posted, you don't need to iterate of it, there's no loop (see Barmar answer for that).

But considering your JSON would be a correct array, it would look like this (note `users` holding an array of objects):

```
{"users":[{"id":"1","username":"admin","email":"alex@xmdevs.com"}, {"id":"2","username":"user","email":"user@xmdevs.com"}]}
```

Then you could iterate like this:

```
var i = 0,
    userList = json_obj.users,
    userCount = userList.length,
    output = '<ul>';

for(i; i < userCount ;i++){
    output+="<li>" + userList[i].username + ",  " + userList[i].email + "</li>";
}
output+="</ul>";
```

Don't use for in, or it will iterate over prototype properties as well.

Answer (score 1):

This should help : http://jsfiddle.net/c3zxLsh6/

```
var obj = {"id":"1","username":"admin","email":"alex@xmdevs.com"};
for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var val = obj[key];
    $("#myList").append("<li>" + val + "</li>");
  }
}
```